# unable to update metasploit framework

Tags: linux, backtracking

i am new to backtrack 5 r3. when i try to exec the command `msfupdate` i get the following error.

> An error occured while installing pg (0.15.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.15.0'` succeeds before bundling.

Comment: Have you made sure that running `gem install pg -v '0.15.0` succeeds?

Comment: no, but could you plz tell me how do i do that ?

Answer (score 2):

I have modified this file : /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/i686-linux/rbconfig.rb

changed the line => CONFIG["LIBRUBYARG_STATIC"] = "-Wl,-R -Wl,$(libdir) -L$(libdir)  -l$(RUBY_SO_NAME)-static"
by => CONFIG["LIBRUBYARG_STATIC"] = "-Wl,-R -Wl,$(libdir) -L$(libdir) "

go to /opt/metasploit/msf3 and run /opt/metasploit/ruby/bin/bundle install

CREDIT -- http://top-hat-sec.com/forum/index.php?topic=2668.0 -- BOBBY

Comment: This worked perfectly for me; however, the path of rbconfig.rb for BackTrack5R3 64bit is: /opt/metasploit/ruby/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/rbconfig.rb

Comment: Oh, I've messed with ruby versions a bit on my installation ;) Also 32 bit here :P

Answer (score 0):

### In my ubuntu system

> sudo apt-get install libpq-dev
>
> gem install pg -v '0.15.0'